# How to merge 2 json files in PHP, of which 1 is an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have created json in PHP from different tables. 1 json object returned is an array. How can I merge both with the second one being a sub array of the first. I want to send this as a single json to Xamarin forms (android) with a single get

PHP array merge gives Argument 2 is not an array

```
Json1
{
    "employeeid": "1123",
    "employeename": "EMP 001 NAME",
    "mMacID": "E0138",
    "machinename": "FOS",
    "iscleaning": 1,
    "isperforming": 1,
    "isverifying": 1,
    "cSeqno": 1,
    "cMacID": "E0138",
    "cInterval": 112,
    "cCleanOperationMaxTime": 300,
    "cPerformOperationMaxTime": 600,
    "oSequenceID": 6,
    "oMacID": "E0138",
    "oItemNumber": " ",
    "oBatchNumber": " ",
    "oPONumber": " ",
    "oCompletedOperation": 0,
    "oComplOperStartTime": 0,
    "oCompOperEndndTime": 0,
    "oOperationToContinue": 1
}

Json2 (Array)
[
    {
        "pMachineID": "E0138",
        "pmachinetoLocationSequence": 1,
        "pLocationNumber": 1,
        "pLocationName": "TestLoc1",
        "pLocationInterval": 12,
        "pImageRequiredForVerifying": 1,
        "pErrorFound": 0
    },
    {
        "pMachineID": "E0138",
        "pmachinetoLocationSequence": 1,
        "pLocationNumber": 2,
        "pLocationName": "TestLoc2",
        "pLocationInterval": 15,
        "pImageRequiredForVerifying": 0,
        "pErrorFound": 0
    },
    {
        "pMachineID": "E0138",
        "pmachinetoLocationSequence": 1,
        "pLocationNumber": 3,
        "pLocationName": "TESTLOC3",
        "pLocationInterval": 18,
        "pImageRequiredForVerifying": 0,
        "pErrorFound": 0
    },
    {
        "pMachineID": "E0138",
        "pmachinetoLocationSequence": 1,
        "pLocationNumber": 1,
        "pLocationName": "LOC1",
        "pLocationInterval": 12,
        "pImageRequiredForVerifying": 0,
        "pErrorFound": 0
    }
]
```

I want the second in as an array in the first.

Comment: What is your expected outout put ?

Comment: just to make it clear. It is sort of master detail form. Where for one master row multiple records from detail table will be returned. There will be only one master record and related multiple records. I am generating this from PHP. I tried multi dimensional arrays in php but I am going wrong some where.

Comment: PHP code as follows:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply decode the 2 JSON String and then add the arrays to the class like this

```
$js1 = '{
    "employeeid": "1123",
    "employeename": "EMP 001 NAME",
    "mMacID": "E0138",
    "machinename": "FOS",
    "iscleaning": 1,
    "isperforming": 1,
    "isverifying": 1,
    "cSeqno": 1,
    "cMacID": "E0138",
    "cInterval": 112,
    "cCleanOperationMaxTime": 300,
    "cPerformOperationMaxTime": 600,
    "oSequenceID": 6,
    "oMacID": "E0138",
    "oItemNumber": " ",
    "oBatchNumber": " ",
    "oPONumber": " ",
    "oCompletedOperation": 0,
    "oComplOperStartTime": 0,
    "oCompOperEndndTime": 0,
    "oOperationToContinue": 1
}';

$js2 = '[
    {
        "pMachineID": "E0138",
        "pmachinetoLocationSequence": 1,
        "pLocationNumber": 1,
        "pLocationName": "TestLoc1",
        "pLocationInterval": 12,
        "pImageRequiredForVerifying": 1,
        "pErrorFound": 0
    },
    {
        "pMachineID": "E0138",
        "pmachinetoLocationSequence": 1,
        "pLocationNumber": 2,
        "pLocationName": "TestLoc2",
        "pLocationInterval": 15,
        "pImageRequiredForVerifying": 0,
        "pErrorFound": 0
    },
    {
        "pMachineID": "E0138",
        "pmachinetoLocationSequence": 1,
        "pLocationNumber": 3,
        "pLocationName": "TESTLOC3",
        "pLocationInterval": 18,
        "pImageRequiredForVerifying": 0,
        "pErrorFound": 0
    },
    {
        "pMachineID": "E0138",
        "pmachinetoLocationSequence": 1,
        "pLocationNumber": 1,
        "pLocationName": "LOC1",
        "pLocationInterval": 12,
        "pImageRequiredForVerifying": 0,
        "pErrorFound": 0
    }
]';

$j1 = json_decode($js1);
$j2 = json_decode($js2);

// You may want to give this a more sensible name than `theArrays`
$j1->theArrays = $j2;

print_r($j1);

$new_json_string = json_encode($j1);

echo $new_json_string;
```

RESULT of `print_r($j1)`

```
stdClass Object
(
    [employeeid] => 1123
    [employeename] => EMP 001 NAME
    [mMacID] => E0138
    [machinename] => FOS
    [iscleaning] => 1
    [isperforming] => 1
    [isverifying] => 1
    [cSeqno] => 1
    [cMacID] => E0138
    [cInterval] => 112
    [cCleanOperationMaxTime] => 300
    [cPerformOperationMaxTime] => 600
    [oSequenceID] => 6
    [oMacID] => E0138
    [oItemNumber] =>  
    [oBatchNumber] =>  
    [oPONumber] =>  
    [oCompletedOperation] => 0
    [oComplOperStartTime] => 0
    [oCompOperEndndTime] => 0
    [oOperationToContinue] => 1
    [theArrays] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [pMachineID] => E0138
                    [pmachinetoLocationSequence] => 1
                    [pLocationNumber] => 1
                    [pLocationName] => TestLoc1
                    [pLocationInterval] => 12
                    [pImageRequiredForVerifying] => 1
                    [pErrorFound] => 0
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [pMachineID] => E0138
                    [pmachinetoLocationSequence] => 1
                    [pLocationNumber] => 2
                    [pLocationName] => TestLoc2
                    [pLocationInterval] => 15
                    [pImageRequiredForVerifying] => 0
                    [pErrorFound] => 0
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [pMachineID] => E0138
                    [pmachinetoLocationSequence] => 1
                    [pLocationNumber] => 3
                    [pLocationName] => TESTLOC3
                    [pLocationInterval] => 18
                    [pImageRequiredForVerifying] => 0
                    [pErrorFound] => 0
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [pMachineID] => E0138
                    [pmachinetoLocationSequence] => 1
                    [pLocationNumber] => 1
                    [pLocationName] => LOC1
                    [pLocationInterval] => 12
                    [pImageRequiredForVerifying] => 0
                    [pErrorFound] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am using PHP to get the data from the table. First set from master table and second set from details table. for each table result I am encoding into json. IS it possible to merge the same in array and then output to json.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json_decode` and  `array_merge` to approach this

```
$json1ToArray = json_decode($json1, true);
$json2ToArray = json_decode($json2, true);
$res = array_merge($json1ToArray, $json2ToArray);
print_r($res);
```

[Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/EhFJ6)